# How to add prefix to rows of a columns if (conditions met)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with certain columns and rows and in which I need to add prefix to rows from one of the columns if it meet certain condition,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a',0,2,3,5],'col2':['PFD_1','PFD_2','PFD_3','PFD_4','PFD_5']})
Samples=pd.DataFrame({'Sam':['PFD_1','PFD_5']})
```

And I need to add a suffix to df.col2 based on values in Samples dataframe, and I tried it with np.where as following,

```
df['col2'] = np.where(df.col2.isin(samples.Sam),'Yes' + df.col2, 'Non_'+ df.col2)
```

Whhich throws error as,

```
TypeError: can only perform ops with scalar values
```

It doesn't return what I am asking for, and throwing errors
 in the end the data frame should look like,

```
>>>df.head()

col col2
a   Yes_PFD_1
0   no_PFD_2
2   no_PFD_3
3   no_PFD_4
5   Yes_PFD_5
```

Comment: For me it works, what is error?

Comment: Renaming `Samples` to `samples` should do the trick.

Comment: `df['col2'] = np.where(df.col2.isin(samples.Sam),'Yes_' + df.col2, 'no_'+ df.col2)` need but it seems there is something else wrong.

Comment: yes, something is wrong which I cant find :)

Comment: Yes I have pasted the error in my question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code worked fine for me once I changed the capitalization of 'samples' ..

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['a',0,2,3,5],'col2': ['PFD_1','PFD_2','PFD_3','PFD_4','PFD_5']})
Samples=pd.DataFrame({'Sam':['PFD_1','PFD_5']})
df['col2'] = np.where(df.col2.isin(Samples.Sam),'Yes' + df.col2, 'Non_'+ df.col2)
df['col2']
```

Outputs ..

```
0     YesPFD_1
1    Non_PFD_2
2    Non_PFD_3
3    Non_PFD_4
4     YesPFD_5
Name: col2, dtype: object
```

Comment: I would appreciate if you could answer this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55035784/typeerror-can-only-perform-ops-with-scalar-values @ashishsingal Thanks